# Parity using "modulo"

Tags: algorithm, parity

I ran into this, while looking up algorithms that find parity, which is supposedly efficient:

```js
function usingModulo(v) {
    v ^= v >> 1
    v ^= v >> 2
    v = (v & 0x11111111) * 0x11111111
    return (v >> 28) & 1
}
```

Could some one please explain how this actually works?

Comment: Operators are very specific to language, so it would help to know what language the code snippet was written in.

Comment: It would also be very helpful for you to learn more (or refresh) about bitwise operations, like XOR and AND and SHIFT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v ^= v >> 1
```

After this, bit 2i in v is the parity of bits 2i and 2i+1.

```
v ^= v >> 2
```

After this, bit 4i in v is the parity of bits 4i,4i+1,4i+2,4i+3.

```
v = (v & 0x11111111) * 0x11111111
```

After this, the top 4 bits of the v contain the sum of the bits at position 4i in the old v, and in particular the bit at position 28 will contain the least significant bit of the sum, which will be the parity of all the bits in the input number.

```
return (v >> 28) & 1
```

This extracts the bit at position 28 (the parity of all bits).

UPDATE

To explain more about the multiplication in step 3 it may help to think of the multiplication as a series of shifts and adds.

For example, to multiply a number x by 111 in base 10, you can add up 100x and 10x and x.

Similarly, multiplying x by 0x11111111 is the same as shifting x by 0,4,8,... and adding the results.

When thinking as a series of shifts and adds, it may make more sense that the top bits will contain all the parities shifted and added together.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Peter. I'm still trying to wrap my head around step 3 a bit more.. I see what it does, how I still don't understand __why__ it works. Not sure if it's just me missing some hint on bit manipulation.. Would appreciate any elaboration if possible :)

Comment: I've added some more explanation